# Bride compilation error

Tags: ros, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I'm trying to install bride following those [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/bride), but when I try to run the command 'make' inside bride folder I get this error:

```
mkdir -p build
if [ ! -f eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz.md5sum" && false; fi
/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR2/eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz build/eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz `awk {'print $1'} eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz.md5sum`
[rosbuild] Downloading http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR2/eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz to build/eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz...Done
[rosbuild] Checking md5sum on build/eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz
[rosbuild] ERROR: md5sum mismatch (027fb35a730ff1f5673a14795a9375f3 != 4d66aa3aeb1c23769fa69f080ccda211) on build/eclipse-modeling-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz; aborting
make: *** [build/eclipse/unpacked] Error 1
```

I triyed both with release 0.2 and branch groovy. I'm working with Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit and with ros hydro. Can someone help me?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121201/bride-compilation-error/) by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 808 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [installation page](https://github.com/ipa320/bride/wiki/Installation) was [updated recently](https://github.com/ipa320/bride/wiki/_compare/9024dab01d324e8d7d453e819bd60969bdba52a0%5E...9024dab01d324e8d7d453e819bd60969bdba52a0) to utilize `catkin_make`, which I have no problem with in building.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-05-06**:
Thanks I downloaded it using apt-get!